# Can I use RequestFactory without getId() and getVersion() methods?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

We are trying to use `RequestFactory` with an existing Java entity model.  Our Java entities all implement a `DomainObject` interface and expose a `getObjectId()` method (this name was chosen as `getId()` can be ambiguous and conflict with the domain object's *actual* ID from the domain being modeled.

The `ServiceLayerDecorator` interface allows for customization of ID and Version property lookup strategies.

```
public class MyServiceLayerDecorator extends ServiceLayerDecorator {
    @Override
    public Object getId(Object object) {
        DomainObject domainObject = (DomainObject) object;
        return domainObject.getObjectId();
    }
}
```

So far, so good.  However, trying to deploy this solution yields runtime errors.  In particular, `RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator` complains:

```
[ERROR] There is no getId() method in type com.mycompany.server.MyEntity
```

Then later on:

```
[ERROR] Type type com.mycompany.client.MyEntityProxy was previously marked as bad
[ERROR] The type com.mycompany.client.MyEntityProxy did not pass RequestFactory validation
[ERROR] Unexpected error
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.UnexpectedException: The type com.mycompany.client.MyEntityProxy did not pass RequestFactory validation
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.die(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:212) ~[gwt-servlet.jar:na]
```

My question is - why does the `ServiceLayerDecorator` allow for customized ID and Version lookup strategies if `RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator` is hardcoding the convention of `getId()` and `getVersion()`?

I guess I could override `ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveClass()` to ignore "poisoned" proxy classes but at this point it seems like I'm fighting the framework too much...

Comment: After digging through `RequestFactoryInterfaceValidator` and re-reading the docs, it seems like I might need to use a custom `Locator` type here...

Comment: A more fundamental question applies however.  What's the use of allowing global override of `getId()` and `getVersion()` in the `ServiceLayerDecorator` if I still need to tag each `EntityProxy` with a specific `Locator` that defines this behavior as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of options, some of which have already been mentioned:

- `Locator`. I like to make a single Locator for the entire proj, or at least for groups of related objects that have similar key types. The getId() call will be able to invoke your DomainObject.getObjectId() method and return that value. Note that the `getDomainType()` method is currently unused, and can return null or throw an exception.
- `ValueProxy`. Instead of having your objects map to something RF can understand as an entity, map them to plain value objects - no id or version required. RF misses out on a lot of clever things it can do, especially with regard to avoiding sending redundant data to the server.
- `ServiceLayerDecorator`. This worked pre 2.4, but with the annotation processing that goes on now, it works less well, since it tries to do some of the work for you. It seems ServiceLayerDecorator has lost a lot of its teeth in the last few months - in theory, you could use it to rebuild getters to talk directly to your persistence mechanism, but now that the annotation processing verifies your code, that is no longer an option.

Big issue in all of this is that RequestFactory is designed to solve a single problem, and solve it well: Allow developers to use POJOs mapped to some persistence mechanism, and refer to those objects from the client, following certain conventions to avoid writing extra code or configuration.

As a result, it solves its own problem pretty well, and ends up being a bad fit for many other problems/use-cases. You might be finding that it isn't worth it: if so, a few thoughts you might consider:

- RPC. It isn't perfect for much, but it does an okay job for a lot.
- AutoBeans (which RF is based on) is still a pretty fast, lightweight way to send data over the wire and get it into the app. You could build your own wrapper around it, like RF has done, and slim down the problem it is trying to solve to just your use-case.